# Is this an open set in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is $\{(x,y)\mid y = \sin \frac {1}{x}, x>0\}$ an open set?
(It is living in $\mathbb R^2$.)

I think it should be open because $(0,0)$ seems to be a limit point of this set while it is not an element of the set.

But solutions tell me it is closed?

Comment: It has no interior, so no, it isn't open. The graph of any continuous function on any subset of $\mathbb R$ cannot be open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Ohhhhh, awesome.

Comment: But you seem confused - "not closed" is not the same as "open." It definitely is not a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$, either.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes. Actually, I forgot the interior of an open set.

Comment: That comment doesn't give me the feeling that you've understood my comments. Do you think that a set which isn't open is closed? The solution you've been given - that it is closed - is false.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I knew that a set may be open or closed or both or neither. From your hint, Let me tell what I learned that is this example is neither open nor closed and the reason is it has no interior and besides it doesn't contain all its limit points at least (0,0), is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set is certainly not open, because it doesn't contain any neighborhood of the point $(2/\pi,1)$: the line $x=2/\pi$ intersects the set only at that point, while the intersection would be larger if the set contained a neighborhood of $(2/\pi,1)$.

The fact that the set is not open doesn't of course imply it's closed. Nor the fact that it doesn't contain *one* of its limit points implies it's open: consider (in $\mathbb{R}$, but examples on the plane are easy as well) the set $[0,1)$ that doesn't contain its limit point $1$, but is not open.

Comment: I think union a set of {$(0,y) | -1 ≤ y ≤ 1$}, it will be closed, right?

Comment: @Frank Yes, that's the set of limit points.

Answer (score 0):

The set $S$ is surely not closed. $(0,0)$ doesn't belong to it while you can find points of $S$ as close as you want from $(0,0)$.

$S$ is also surely not open if you consider it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The point $P=(\frac{1}{\pi},0)$ belongs to $S$ while you can't find an open ball centered on $P$ included in $S$.